With MapStruct, every componentModel field option is read as Default
It's not important if I put cdi, jakarta or even spring.
The compiler only read "default".
I nead jakarta.
@Mapper(componentModel = "jakarta-cdi")
public interface DepartmentMapper {
    DepartmentDto toDepartmentDto(Department department);
    List<DepartmentDto> toDepartmentDtoList(List<Department> departments);
    Department toDepartmentEntity(DepartmentDto departmentDto);
}

    @Inject
    DepartmentMapper depMapper;

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type dev.fullstackcode.dto.DepartmentMapper and qualifiers [@Default]
    - injection target: dev.fullstackcode.dao.DepartmentService#depMapper
    - declared on CLASS bean [types=[dev.fullstackcode.dao.DepartmentService, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Default, @Any], target=dev.fullstackcode.dao.DepartmentService]

With MapStruct 1.3.1 the eroor was he was trying to use javax version of the notation even the project have only jakarta and so there was a class not found.
What I need to update/downgrade?
Edit 1:
Using default Injection with constructor works. Still don't know what problem jakarta has.
Edit 2:
I removed @ApplicationScoped from Mapper interface.

DepartmentMapper is an interface - the bean defining scope annotation (@ApplicationScoped) will not work there. You need to annotate actual implementation class or use producer methods. Note that the interface class will be in the resulting set of bean types and you can still use that type for injection.

remove @ApplicationScoped because generated bean is annotated with the appropriated scope

Removed. No changes. All it's the same. I did Clean and Maven Update to be sure.
